# Negate a group as [^(?:\n\n\n\n)]+

Tags: python, regex

I am constructing such a regex

```
text_regex = re.compile(r"""(
^\n{4} #start with 4 blank lines
[^(?:\n\n\n\n)]+ #negate 4 blank lines to retrieve the content in the middle
\n{4}$ #end with 4 blank lines
)""", re.VERBOSE)
```

I tried multiple times with a well-formatted text which I deliberately separate each item with 4 blank lines

```
mo = text_regex.findall(text)
In [131]: len(mo)
Out[131]: 0
```

How could I handle `[^(?:\n\n\n\n)]+` to retrieve all the content between the 4 "\n"?

Comment: Why `re.findall`? Are you validating or extracting? `[^...]` is a negated character class that only matches any 1 char other than those inside the set. Regardless how many times you write `\n`, it is just the same as `[^():?\n]+`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you show an example input/output?

Comment: Why not just split on `"\n\n\n\n"`?

Comment: What does "negate 4 blank lines" mean? What's your regex supposed to match?

Comment: It does sound as if you need `if s.startswith('\n\n\n\n') and s.endswith('\n\n\n\n'): print(s.strip())`,

Comment: @melpomene If there are more than 4 newlines that would produce empty elements which the OP may not want?

Comment: I intend to capture and categorize with (?P<name>) in the regex @melpomene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters sets are **sets** so they do *not* contain repeats!

If you want to retrieve portions of text that are delimited by 4 newlines you could simply use this regex:

```
\n{4}(.*?)\n{4}
```

and specify `re.DOTALL`. The non-greediness will ensure that you want "gobble" 4 newlines inside the "middle block".

However that is probably inefficient. An other way of doing that is using a regex like this:

```
\n{4}(.*\n{,3}[^\n])*\n{4}
```

*Without* using `re.DOTALL`.

---

I'd probably do this instead anyway:

```
re.split(r'\n{4,}', text)
```

And optionally remove the last empty element at the end of the result.

Comment: How smart of your solution~~~~`\n{4}(.*\n{,3}[^\n])*\n{4}` ^_^

Comment: I failed to  follow `The non-greediness will ensure that you want "gobble" 4 newlines inside the "middle block"` How nongreedy ensure 4 newlines.

Comment: @Painter Consider the text `<a>hello<a/>`, if you'd like to match just the initial tag `<a>`. The regex `<.*>` will match the whole text because `.*` will match `a>hello<a/`. If you use `<.*?>` instead the `.*?` matches only `a`. In this case instead of `<` and `>` you have 4 newlines. If you let `.*` with `re.DOTALL` you will endup putting many "middle blocks" into just the `.*`, by making it non-greedy using `.*?` you avoid this behaviour.